# Good resources to learn mobile adaptation techniques

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

I'm a web developer that has worked with ASP.NET based portal applications for several years. Recently, my company tasked me with developing a mobile version of our portal product.

I have found quite a few resources about developing mobile web applications, and have made great progress in my task; however, the one topic that I have yet to find any valuable resources on is [Content Adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_adaptation) (specifically adaptation with ASP.NET):

> Content adaptation is the action of transforming content to adapt to device capabilities. Content adaptation is usually related to mobile devices, which require special handling because of their limited computational power, small screen size, and constrained keyboard functionality.

I've found some resources on MSDN to be slightly useful, but haven't seen much in the way of concrete examples.

---

Does anyone know of good sites or books for this topic, that include concrete examples?

**NOTE**: I usually code in `C#`, but can translate most languages so it doesn't need to be `C#` focused (though it is preferred).

Comment: You can see some ideas in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844020/way-to-do-content-adaptation-to-mobile

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that your best experiences are going to be looking at

WURFL and the mailing list wmlprogramming

From there I would also recommend reading mobiforge as they have alot of articles about how to do things for mobile even if it is written more for Java and PHP

Overall I have found that the Java/PHP community is alot further ahead in mobile development than the ASP.NET community.

I put that down to the poor implementation of the mobile controls by Microsoft.