# Is it redundant using jQuery Mobile and a responsive layout /CSS media queries?

Tags: layout, css, jquery-mobile, media-queries, responsive-design

I was checking out http://mediaqueri.es/ today and found out that the websites adapt fantastically to mobile devices. So i wondered if using jQuery Mobile and a response/adaptive layout with media queries together would be redundant, since by using only media queries seems to be a good approach.
Is it really redundant or am i tripping on caffeine?

EDIT

Example:
I don't see how [this website](http://sasquatchfestival.com/) would benefit from using jQuery Mobile, since it's very well done using media queries.

And to be fair, i don't see [this website](http://m.travelwisconsin.com/) being done without jQuery Mobile, hehe. Reproducing the "native app" look and feel without jQuery Mobile would be hard, is this correct?

Comment: You can see someone telling about here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844020/way-to-do-content-adaptation-to-mobile

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think jQuery Mobile does not make media queries obsolete. One of the great advantages of jQuery mobile in my opinion, is that it makes things like form elements more mobile friendly by making them bigger etc. But if you want to change other things depending on the device, like say the size of images, you might still want to use media queries to load the appropriate css file.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Mobile is great, and I love it!, but I dislike the fact that they hide their shortcomings, even when they're in use on their own demo.
And here it is: if you use media queries to add blocks of content on bigger devices, you have to limit the jqm effects (transitions mainly), and be very careful about planning your layout/loading of pages/content.

They're even using media queries on their own demo (using "last minute CSS hacks") to provide for a two column layout with side menu on tablets and desktops. You'll also notice that the only effect they can use is fade, since the whole page acts as a page and you can't transition just part of the content. In other words, the side menu is duplicated and shown again on linked pages. This isn't a problem just because of transition effects, it makes site planning much more complicated. I'd like to use this for a full featured website, but the limitations might be too much for what I'd like to be able to do.

So, to answer your question, it isn't redundant, but it does make it so that JQM isn't as simple as it's designed to be. For those who are already doing a lot of CSS tweaking for their desktop web apps, it might not be too much work for you, but before you begin I would make sure you have a very thorough understanding of how JQM works.

Answer (score 0):

i think jquery mobile its awesome if you got an webapp.. like an app with a lot of forms and tables and that kind of stuff... not just a website thats shows information...