# Jquery Mobile or Responsive Design?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, responsive-design

I've been doing a lot of research on building Responsive design. So I came across this article from here:

[Is it redundant using jQuery Mobile and a responsive layout /CSS media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277085/is-it-redundant-using-jquery-mobile-and-a-responsive-layout-css-media-queries)

And it got me thinking. Won't Responsive Design replace making a Jquery Mobile website? Because responsive design is the same thing JQ Mobile does but better because you have more control over each area. Correct me if I am wrong I was just wondering and learning! So why would anyone want to use JQuery Mobile or even using JQ Mobile with a responsive design?

Comment: I read the answers, I still don't get it

Comment: Choice is broader: native app and/or dedicated mobile (and/or tablet) site and/or RWD (or RESS). There isn't a single answer to this problem, there are a lot of constraints outside of programming field (which is the only type of uestions accepted here btw) and each site/service needs different considerations

Answer (score 2):

you probably won't use jquery mobile if you are supporting desktop screens too. Jquery mobile is more useful when it comes to mobiles and tablets.

Responsive design on the other hand enables you to display information on your website and keep it readable and usable irrespective of the screen size. Refer Twitter Bootstrap if you want to support all the screen sizes.

**Update**

Normally you have different UI for desktop and mobile/tablets. So based on the screen-size you can decide how each component(header, navbar, sidebar, body, footer) will be laid out on the viewport and how the design should be.

For example your website will have a single column layout for mobiles and 2-column layout for tablets as against your desktop version.

Comment: So if a customer asked you to build a desktop and mobile/tablet website. What would you use Responsive or a Standard Desktop Site with a Jquery Mobile site?

Comment: So with that said in your update why not replace jquery with a Responsive design (RD) since a RD has three plateforms (Desktop, Tablet and Mobile)? What I am confused about is what is really the purpose of a JQ mobile site if you have RD? Does JQ Mobile automatically re size the site for a table differently then a smartphone? Thanks again for the info!

Comment: jquery mobile is framework which helps you to build single page applications faster. It has has several built in features that you don't need to write it yourself from scratch and its responsive too. It really depends on what kind of application/website you are building.

Answer (score 2):

The JQuery Mobile icons can be the size you want as long as it's 14px...

While this is not entirely true, you must have a very good understanding of how CSS is used in JQuery Mobile to change the size of icons, let alone change them in media queries.

Buttons can have text and/or icons. It would be nice to have buttons with both icon and text on a desktop PC, and only an icon on a mobile device. Well this seems to be even harder because the format of the button is specified by giving btn-* classes to the <button> (or <a>) element. For instance:

```
<a href="#caddy" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-caddy ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon">Caddy</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="#order" class="ui-btn-a ui-corner-all ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Checkout</a>
```

So JQuery Mobile adds more constraints to what you can do with CSS, thus making it harder to build responsive interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to go with jQuery mobile if you are targeting mobile and handheld devices with smaller screens than a desktop.

The advantange with jQuery Mobile is that it provides you with some extra features like page events, page transitions, theming etc. It's easier ans simpler compared to writing code to perform all those manually.

Also, jQuery Mobile uses more of a fluid layout which means your pages fit in most of the screen sizes. Where as responsive design lets you display/hide information based on the screen size.

Comment: So if a customer asked you to build a desktop and mobile/tablet website. What would you use Responsive design or a Standard Desktop website with a Jquery Mobile site?

Comment: It depends on what kind of website is required. For general websites like those News I would go with responsive design. For complicated web applications like Twitters or Facebook, I would build a separate application for mobiles and tablets. 
I believe Reponsive Design is the future anyways :)

Comment: Well that's what I'm wondering will Responsive Design (RD) replace Jquery mobile since it has three plateforms (desktop, tablet and a mobile layout) on top of that it re sizes when you move the browser in or view it on a mobile vs desktop or tablet vs desktop and so on. Other then the bells and whisles you get with JQ such as transition and so on what else can or does it do to beat a Responsive Design?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a responsive design web application, may I suggest you follow the [Mobile-first](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/) approach which basically means you design and build your applications for mobile first instead of doing it after the PC version is done?

Here's an example taken from the article:

```
 /*Large screen styles first - Avoid*/
.product-img {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 40.5em) {
  .product-img {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
}
/* mobile first approach */
@media screen and (min-width: 40.5em) {
  .product-img {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

In that way, you may feel the jQuery mobile is redundant in your development process.
Of couse, as others have mentioned, jQuery mobile comes in handy when you want to build a separate app for mobiles and tablets.

Comment: What would be the benefits of building a site from mobile up? At the end of the day it seems no matter what approach you take you just have to face reality and know you will have to build/layout three website (desktop, tablet and mobile) no matter what you do. At least at the end of the day that's what it seems like.

Comment: Yes, you surely have to build 3 layout versions. But following the Mobile-first you will have your codes written simpler, smaller and more maintainable. See my updated answer for an example.

Answer (score -3):

if you want to build mobile site then you have to use jQuery mobile, if u want to have support for desktop browser and for mobile browser, then you have to  use bootstrap or foundation framework to make responsive website.