# How to make a website resolution same in all browsers

Tags: html, css

i have built a site,but the thing i noticed when testing was, it appears in different resolutions in other system.i want to make the webpage appear perfectly fit to any resolution..how to do this can anyone help me? thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you asking how you can automatically make a user's screen a particular resolution?!  Because that's the only interpretation I can make from your question.  If so, it's simple... you can't.  If it's not, please make your question a lot, lot clearer

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to explain what you mean by "it appears in different resolutions in other system". Are you talking about different browser window sizes?

Comment: do you use % as width unit for you're website?

Comment: No but the website should should fit perfectly into screen of any resolution.

Comment: If you want to create something that fits perfectly into everybody's screen, then write an iPhone / iPad application. Browsers come in every shape and colour and size... and as a result you are going to find neigh-on-impossible to make it "fit perfectly"

Comment: Maybe are the OP wanting some Responsive layout tutorial? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061572/responsive-layout-tutorial]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your website responsive you can use css media queries.

[Refer to this link](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 2):

Create your site under 1000px or by using a 960 grid layout. 
It will fit into all versions.

For Mobile - use CSS media queries or create your site by using percentages (target/context=result) and use ems for fonts and margins.