# Blank space on the right side on phone

Tags: html, css

I have a problem about the width between monitor screen and phone. However, it's working well on the PC but not working on phone as there are blank space on the right side. The following code are below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="home-about">
    <div class="middle-align">
        <h1> ABOUT ME </h1> 
        <p> TESTING TESTING TESTING TESTING TESTING </p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#home-about {
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    height:880px;
    padding:150px 50px 50px 50px;
    background-color:#d24d57;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:25px;
}

.middle-align {
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

First of all, the colour of `#home-about` is `#d24d57`. The color is fully shown on monitor screen but not on the phone.

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8jhyebg3/).
As you can see JSFIDDLE, Try to scroll right, there are no colour, only white colour. How to fill in `#d23d57` as well. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this link for responsive design 
[Responsive layout tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061572/responsive-layout-tutorial)
Or you can use Bootstrap for Responsive html development [Get-Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).
Hope this help

*These suggestions should be a comment but cannot do that cause not got these privilages*

Comment: I know about bootstrap. I'm just having fun to design by myself. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

Move `width: 1200px` to your `#home-about`:

```
#home-about {
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    padding:150px 50px 50px 50px;
    background-color:#d24d57;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:25px;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8jhyebg3/2/).

Comment: Hello, I just realised that it's working on PC but not working on mobile phone. However, can you check the site on your phone? It's www.anthonywebdeveloper.com.

Comment: You should make it responsive, the first step is remove all `width: 1200px` and `min-width: 1200px` from your stylesheet.

Comment: I have done the first step. What should I do next? However, I have problem with the footer. It shows blank space on the right side again. @Rox