# Is it possible to hide the overflow of the body for computer and not for phone?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, responsive

is it possible to hide to overflow only if the user is on a computer or something other then a phone?
I've already tried hiding the overflow with
overflow: hidden;
but that hides the overflow for phone users as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at CSS media queries, it's very simple. It applies some CSS on large screens but not on phones, for instance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061572/responsive-layout-tutorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive layout tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061572/responsive-layout-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp).

For example:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* this is for mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    body{
        overflow: visible;
    }   
}
```